# Adding film grain only to the CGI and not camera projection?

Tags: camera, compositing-nodes

I have set up a camera projection of a street with buildings. Problem is the photo is way too grainy and my CG car looks too clean. So I need to match the grain on the car to the photo I'm using for the camera projection. I have added film grain using a downloaded overlay before to CG scenes. But now I need to add only to the CG car and possibly its shadow and not the whole scene. How would I do that in Blender? In the compositor? I could easily do that in Fusion, but that would mean rendering different passes from Blender and adding to the render time too. If I can output it directly and finished from Blender, it would be better.

I have tried following some tutorials where they use the Compositing tab, but they are all focused on adding grain to the whole render/scene. I see that my only input option for the Render Layer node in the compositor is Scene. I can’t choose the car there, which I had thought would be the way. But I only need to add grain to the car and possibly its shadow, which is done via a shadow catcher.

I'm totally new to the compositing tab. Have some basic experience with the shading tab.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

**This could be done using ID masks inside Compositor
Related video on youtube [Id Masks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2JKviMX9rE) (tho it's old I'll add a couple of screenshots where specific settings are located)**

Compositor setup:
[image: Use color socket in the mix node to plug in your grain]

Enable object index and material index before Rendering inside Propertied Tab > View Layer > Passes > Data
[image: Here]

Configure the pass index for each object
[image: Here]

Or for material if you want
[image]

Now, inside the compositor, under your id mask, configure the index you specified for material or object
[image]
Index MA - material pass index, OB - object

**And another note**: you will need to rerender in order to use new configurations